# How to use lucene analyzers with Elasticsearch java API

Tags: elasticsearch, java-client

I want to build elastisearch queries using JAVA API. I want to know how to can use Lucene analyzers in elasticsearch java programs. I have checked `QueryBuilders` and tried to use analyzers directly as below.

```
QueryBuilder builder = QueryBuilders.matchQuery(searchString, fields).analyzer("porterstem");
```

But, it turned out to be wrong. If any one tried it, could you please give me some information?

Answer (score 0):

You should define your analyzer in mapping.
So the analyzer will be used at index time and at query time.

Answer (score 0):

ANALYZERS are used to analyze the documents that your are indexed. Analysis means it Ll split,the text in to tokens, normalize it, and also Lower case your indexed doc text. This analysis process Ll b more helpful while you search and searching will be faster..

You can mention analyzer while you query . But analyze the stored documents during query time. Ll b expensive.  So analyze the document during indexing time.  ES will analysis the doc during indexed and query time will b less and faster result. 
So mention analyzers in mapping and searching efficiently..

For more information about analyzer refer
https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/analysis/Analyzer.html